# Angular code is not reading a JSON array correctly when it did previously

Tags: json, angularjs

We have a service which returns a JSON array as follows:

```
{ "data" : [{ "time" : "2023-11-16T18:55:00.0000000Z", "value" : "638356352165652595" }] }
```

Our angular code has this method to call this:

```
dataArrayJson: {
    method: 'GET', params: {endpoint: 'Data', p: 'CalcJson'},
    isArray: true, withCredentials: true, cancellable: true
}
```

and this is called from this code:

```
   self.activePipelineRequest = mapService.dataArrayJson(
      {
        exp: exp,
      },
      function (response) {
        if (self.pipelinePhase) {
          self.pipelinePhase.complete = true;
          self.pipelinePhase.sample =
            response.length > 0 ? response[0].time : null;
          self.pipelinePhase.sampleId =
            response.length > 0 ? response[0].value : null;

          //self.invalidateFromPhase(self.pipelinePhase.nextPhase);
          self.processPipeline();
        }
      },
      function (err) {},
    );
```

We are now getting the following error:

> Error: [$resource:badcfg] dataArrayJson
> https://errors.angularjs.org/1.8.3/$resource/badcfg?p0=array&p1=object&p2=GET&p3=https%3A%2F%2Fmap-rainuk-dev.test.co.uk%2FMap%2FData%2FCalcJson
> at
> https://map-client.meniscus.co.uk/bower_components/angular/angular.js:138:12
> at

This has only happened in the last few months. Neither the angular code or the service has changed but now the parsing of the JSON is not working.

I have looked into this in more detail. If I return this JSON:

```
[
    {
        "time": "2023-11-16T17:55:00.0000000Z",
        "value": "638356385254612445"
    }
]
```

it works and this is a valid JSON array.

However, if I return this:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "time": "2023-11-16T17:55:00.0000000Z",
            "value": "638356385254612445"
        }
    ]
}
```

I get the error in the angular code. This is also valid JSON.

Does anyone know why the second JSON string is not valid?